Efficient way to process data for number of views with dates
I am looking for a more efficient way to implement the provided code, which retrieves the number of views for object within a date range (start_date and end_date). The current code achieves the expected result, transforming data into a dictionary structure with names and corresponding daily view counts. However, I believe there might be a more optimized approach.
Here's the code snippet for reference:
models.py
class Ad(models.Model):
    ad_type = models.ForeignKey(to=AdType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ad")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="ads")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class AdStat(models.Model):
    class StatType(models.TextChoices):
        VIEWS = "views", _("Views")
        CLICKS = "clicks", _("Clicks")

    ad = models.ForeignKey(to=Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ad_stat")
    stat_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=StatType.choices)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

views.py
@staff_member_required
def ads_number_of_views(request):
    start_date = request.GET.get("start_date")
    end_date = request.GET.get("end_date")

    ads = (
        AdStat.objects.filter(ad__is_active=True, ad__ad_type__slug="desktop-hader")
        .select_related("ad")
        .values("ad__name", "created_at__date")
        .annotate(view_count=Count("id"))
        .order_by("created_at__date")
    )
    if start_date and end_date:
        ads = ads.filter(created_at__gte=start_date, created_at__lte=end_date)
    elif start_date:
        ads = ads.filter(created_at__gte=start_date)
    elif end_date:
        ads = ads.filter(created_at__lte=end_date)

    ads_data = []
    for item in ads:
        ad_name = item["ad__name"]
        date_str = str(item["created_at__date"])
        count = item["view_count"]
        found = False
        for entry in ads_data:
            if entry["name"] == ad_name:
                entry["number_of_views"].append({"created_at": date_str, "count": count})
                found = True
                break

        if not found:
            ads_data.append({"name": ad_name, "number_of_views": [{"created_at": date_str, "count": count}]})
    return JsonResponse(ads, safe=False)

Expected Output.
The code successfully returns a JSON response with the following structure:
[
  {
    "name": "ad1",
    "number_of_views": [
      {"created_at": "2024-03-28", "count": 18},
      {"created_at": "2024-03-30", "count": 47}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "ad2",
    "number_of_views": [
      {"created_at": "2024-03-30", "count": 24},
      {"created_at": "2024-03-31", "count": 33}
    ]
  }
]

Along with efficiency, I'd like to incorporate filtering functionality for Chart.js. Ideally, the user should be able to choose between viewing data by day, month or year. I'm open to exploring alternative approches using Django's ORM capabilities or other optimizations.

Assuming there is no metadata per AdStat, you can count the number on the entry itself
from django.db.models import F
...
stat = Adstat.objects.select_for_update().get_or_create(**args)
stat.count = F("count") + 1
stat.save()

probably works with update_or_create, but I don't have an example right now...
